# Add new entries to explorer context menu with images

Tags: c#

I am unable to add an icon to a custom context menu item in XP but the same works fine in 
windows 7 (Displays the ICON). 
Please help me in solving the issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad idea to use managed code for context menu. See blog [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)